# Can I use node,bower and git on shared server?

Tags: git, hosting, bower, shared

I never really used bower until recently and I'm just starting to dabble with GIT and have installed node js on localhost for testing and learning.

My question is this: As I am a bit of a novice with regards to node, git and bower, I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the processes and how to use them.

For the average web site on a shared host, what is the best approach? I know I can download and install packages from node on localhost but what about when you want to use those same setups on your actual live site within a shared host? What is the best and most common approach? Do people use bower, git and node js on shared hosts?

Apologies if this sounds like a dumb question.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to commit libraries to your project source code, this is redundant and fraught with updating maintenance nightmares, so just commit your `package.json` and your `bower.json` to your git repository and ignore the package folders themselves.

```
echo 'node_modules/' >> .gitignore
git add package.json bower.json .gitignore
git commit -m "add package dependencies"
git push -u origin master
```

Now from your remote server

```
git pull origin master
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,                                                                                    Am afraid I have limited experience with git so not too sure what you mean. Have been looking into Polymer tutorials that use bower and node js. I haven't used git at all in those tuts. I just wondered if people use bower and node js on a shared host. Thanks